# Error when Merges the latest commit on the master branch into all open feature branches

Tags: salesforcedx, cumulusci

I am trying to merge the latest commit on the master branch into all open feature branches but I am getting error for cci task run github_parent_to_children and github_master_to_feature

**C:\AutoMerge>cci task run github_parent_to_children**

```
2020-02-19 17:45:04: Beginning task: MergeBranch
2020-02-19 17:45:04:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python37\Scripts\cci.exe_main.py", line 7, in
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in call
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 209, in new_func
func(config, *args, **kw)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 1257, in task_run
handle_exception_debug(config, debug, no_prompt=no_prompt)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 1240, in task_run
task()
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\core\tasks.py", line 140, in call
self.result = self._run_task()
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\tasks\github\merge.py", line 46, in _run_task
self.repo = self.get_repo()
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\tasks\github\base.py", line 16, in get_repo
self.project_config.repo_owner, self.project_config.repo_name
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\github3\github.py", line 1981, in repository
json = self._json(self._get(url), 200)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\github3\models.py", line 156, in _json
raise exceptions.error_for(response)
github3.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Not Found`
```

**C:\AutoMerge>cci task run github_master_to_feature**

```
2020-02-19 17:57:16: Beginning task: MergeBranch
2020-02-19 17:57:16:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
"main", mod_spec)
File "c:\python37\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Python37\Scripts\cci.exe_main.py", line 7, in
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 764, in call
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 717, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1137, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 956, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 555, in invoke
return callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 209, in new_func
func(config, *args, **kw)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 1257, in task_run
handle_exception_debug(config, debug, no_prompt=no_prompt)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\cli\cci.py", line 1240, in task_run
task()
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\core\tasks.py", line 140, in call
self.result = self._run_task()
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\tasks\github\merge.py", line 46, in _run_task
self.repo = self.get_repo()
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\cumulusci\tasks\github\base.py", line 16, in get_repo
self.project_config.repo_owner, self.project_config.repo_name
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\github3\github.py", line 1981, in repository
json = self._json(self._get(url), 200)
File "c:\python37\lib\site-packages\github3\models.py", line 156, in _json
raise exceptions.error_for(response)
github3.exceptions.NotFoundError: 404 Not Found`
```

Answer (score 1):

There's usually two things that cause this error:

- The `git` section of the `project` top-level section in `cumulusci.yml` is not populated correctly. It should look something like this:

  ```
      git:
          repo_url: https://github.com/your_user_name/your_project
          prefix_beta: beta/
          prefix_release: rel/
  ```

  Make sure the repo URL is correct.
- You are authenticated to GitHub (via `cci service connect github`) as a user who does not have read permission to this repository.

Comment: I have a repository in bitbucket not github, so will it make any difference

Comment: @PronitAgrawal CCI currently only supports GitHub.

Comment: Hi @David,We thought Bitbucket was supported through CumulusCI. Do you guys have any plans to support this in future, we want to implement this functionality using Cumulusci.

Comment: @PronitAgrawal Apologies, I missed this initially. We know that a lot of folks want support for Bitbucket and GitLab, but we're not there yet. PRs welcome! In the meantime, you can use some elements of CumulusCI without GitHub - you won't be able to use repository-to-repository dependencies, or the tasks that create GitHub releases, but other parts of the automation should work.